# How to place an image on top of another image in Android XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an app which is a guide. I have a photograph showing an example, but I need to know, how can I make certain parts of the images clickable, to go to another activity to show more details about that thing.

Or have an image (which will be clicked) on top of the base image?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
have an image (which will be clicked) on top of the base image?
```

1 - 
Can set the Background of Linear layout and add imageView in center of parent.

or

2- Use relative layout with tow image Views

Comment: Thanks!! I used a combination of both. A relative layout inside a table row, with the background of the relative layout set to the base image, then the images required are shown as imageViews.

Thanks again. This worked perfectly. At least on all 3 devices I've tested on with different screen sizes :)

Comment: I suppose, but I couldn't have thought of that without your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can split your main image on rectangular parts, then put them as `ImageView`s using `RelativeLayout` or `TableLayout` (which ever fits best in your case) so their combinations looks like a single image.

On each `ImageView` you can set a click listener using [View.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener l)](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29)

Comment: Thanks for replying! I used a relative layout. I always thought they were a pain to work with, but it isn't too bad if you're doing it the hard way (typing out the code, rather than dragging and dropping)